# Beamer slide navigation does not work when including notes on the left

Tags: beamer, notes, navigation

I have the following MWE below that works perfectly, but to my horror, the awesome navigation circles at the top of the slides do not work (using pdf visualization programs in Ubuntu like Okular and impressive) when I show the notes, only when I hide them.

I really need the navigation to work when adding notes, am I doing something wrong in my code?? Or is it supposed to behave like that (BIG bug IMHO)??

MWE, a really basic slideshow presentation with notes... (really strange that something doesn't work properly at this level of simplicity, does it really have to behave this way?? hard to think there is anything wrong with the code):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{%
    %hide notes
    show notes on second screen=left
    }
\usetheme{Singapore}

\begin{document}    
    \section{Background}
    \subsection{first stuff}
    \begin{frame}
        This is the first slide
        \note{this is the first note}
    \end{frame} 
    \subsection{more stuff}
    \begin{frame}
        This is the second slide
        \note{this is the second note}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I also want to export the same presentation for handouts with the notes at the bottom, with the following code (note the first lines are different), here the slide navigation links do not work either...

```
\documentclass[handout, ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper,border shrink=0.5in] % could also use a4paper
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom} % Beamer manual, section 19.3

\usetheme{Singapore}

\begin{document}    
    \section{Background}
    \subsection{first stuff}
    \begin{frame}
        This is the first slide
        \note{this is the first note}
    \end{frame} 
    \subsection{more stuff}
    \begin{frame}
        This is the second slide
        \note{this is the second note}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Probably the sole reason why I make the presentations with Beamer and not PowerPoint is because of the navigation, but if I cannot keep it when I need to present with notes...

**EDIT**
Please check [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232838/beamer-with-notes-on-the-left-have-navigation-links-working-both-on-slides-rig) that continues from this present question's accepted answer.

Comment: The hyperlinks still exist... at the left page. Change to `show notes on second screen=right` and you will see. The problem may be that `pgfpages` does not modify the coordinates of links.

Comment: [See this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48088/beamer-handout-with-hyperlinks)

Comment: That could be a transient solution, but I cannot change the side of the additional screen every time I make a presentation... I'd rather prefer to keep the notes on the left. Can't pgfpages modify the coordinates of the links somehow?

Comment: I have edited the question to add another option... I want to create the pdf for handouts with the notes at the bottom, but there the links do not work either...

Comment: You are easily horrified ;). (I agree this might be annoying - but horror?!)

Comment: Hahaha. Yeah horror is a strong word! But you know, I switched to Beamer for my slide shows just cause I liked the navigation feature, only to find that now that I got the hang of it and need to include notes for long presentations that I give... the navigation doesn't work. Haha

Comment: I have an idea: add navigation bar to the note-side.

Comment: How can I do that? I would still want the bar to show on the slides though...

Comment: You can have as many bars as you want. But some of them become decoration if the coordinate does not match. That is,  only click the links on the lower-left (logical) page.

Comment: But how do I add the extra bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continued from comments:

I fount the original code in `beamerouterthememiniframes.sty` and replace just one line. See the commented-out line and its next line. It leads to a bar in the old position and a new bar exceeding the right margin of the (logical) page. However, the invisible links of the right bar will coincide with the visible button of the left bar. Magic!

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme plus}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    %\vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \vskip2pt\hbox{\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\addtoheadtemplate{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}\vskip-1.25cm}{}

\begin{document}
    \section{s1}
        \subsection{ss2}
            \frame{{f3}}\frame{{f4}}
        \subsection{ss5}
            \frame{{f6}}\frame{{f7}}
    \section{s8}
        \subsection{ss9}
            \frame{{f10}}\frame{{f11}}
        \subsection{ss12}
            \frame{{f13}}\frame{{f14}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Symbol1, it works as expected!! However, I found really useful the idea of having the navigation at the left along with the notes, but the navigation on the left does not work properly... Let me work on a MWE and I will edit my question

Comment: @DaniCee That deserves a new question. (In case Google found nothing having been done)

Comment: OK I will post another question, I will put the link here

Comment: Hi @Symbol1, please check http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232838/beamer-with-notes-on-the-left-have-navigation-links-working-both-on-slides-rig

I used your same MWE adding some code customizing the notes with navigation. I used another set of slides, as with the ones in your MWE I didn't experience the problem...

Comment: Hi again @Symbol, please check the new thread if you have time, I am stuck with this... Thanks!