# Beamer with notes on the left, have navigation links working both on slides (right) and on notes (left)

Tags: beamer, notes, navigation, pgfpages

Following the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232520/beamer-slide-navigation-does-not-work-when-including-notes-on-the-left), and given a suggestion in one of the comments, I am trying to have working navigation links not only on the slides on the right, but also on the notes on the left.

Working on that same MWE, I customized my notes t include the navigation links, a mini slide and the notes themselves.

However, while the navigation links on the slides (right) work properly, the ones on the left (notes) work buy incorrectly, as they direct to incorrect slides...

Sorry for the long MWE, I included the same set of slides I'm working with, as with other combination of slides I haven't registered those problems. Thanks!

MWE

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme plus}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    %\vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \vskip2pt\hbox{\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\addtoheadtemplate{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}\vskip-1.25cm}{}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%ADDITIONAL CODE
%notes
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain] % Beamer manual, section 19.1
\newlength{\parskipbackup}
\setlength{\parskipbackup}{\parskip}
\newlength{\parindentbackup}
\setlength{\parindentbackup}{\parindent}
\newcommand{\baselinestretchbackup}{\baselinestretch}

\usetemplatenote{
  %for some reason I have to specify a smaller font size and 0.85 paperwidth
  \fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{0.85\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \insertslideintonotes{0.3}

  \setlength{\parindent}{1em} \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%

  \rmfamily \tiny %better \scriptsize for the handout

  \insertnote%

  \setlength{\parskip}{\parskipbackup}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{\parindentbackup}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\baselinestretchbackup}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{document}
    \section{Background}
    \subsection{sub1}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
        \subsection{sub2}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
        \subsection{sub3}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
        \subsection{sub4}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
    \section{Importance and objective}
        \subsection{sub1}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
        \subsection{sub2}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
        \subsection{sub3}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
    \section{Methods}
        \subsection{sub1}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
        \subsection{sub2}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
        \subsection{sub3}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
    \section{Results}
        \subsection{sub1}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
        \subsection{sub2}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
        \subsection{sub3}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
        \subsection{sub4}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
    \section{Future directions}
        \subsection{sub1}
            \begin{frame}SLIDE
            \note{notesnotesnotes}
            \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
The problem yields on the resizing, if the 0.85 is removed from this line

```
 \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{0.85\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
```

and this line is removed as well

```
 \fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont
```

the navigation works as expected, but the navigation bar takes up way too much space... can't it be resized while keeping the links working?

Comment: Although with a lot of warnings, it seems to work fine by my side.

Comment: Have you tried navigating with the links on the left? They direct to incorrect slides. On the other hand, I get no warnings whatsoever (apart from the usual "Font shape" and "Size substitutions with differences" ones...)

Comment: The problem yields on the resizing... if the 0.85 is omitted and the \fontsize line removed, the navigation works, but the bar takes up way too much space... why does this happen??

Comment: Both LaTeX and LuaLaTeX complain a lot but their result works fine. XeLaTeX complains nothing but links fail. Maybe the problem is a little bit deep.

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect this

Comment: I have no complains whatsoever with that code...

Comment: Are you using pdflatex directly?

Comment: LuaLatex + View PDF with texlive 2013, on TexMaker 4.1-1

Answer (score 2):

Replace

> ```
> \fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont
>   \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
>     \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{0.85\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
>   \end{beamercolorbox}%
> ```

By

```
  \tiny
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\hbox{\hskip-30pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
```

Comment: Still some links don't direct to the correct slides...